# get documents based on property values using elasticsearch in nodejs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch and i am new to this technology.I didnot know how to search property values on indices types in elasticsearch using nodejs.My data is

```
{
           "line_num": 1,
           "action1": "ORIGINAL",
           "process_code1": "PENDING",
           "isPR": "Y",
           "req_header_reference_num": "PC5298",
           "req_line_reference_num": "PC5298",
           "pr_line_no": "1",
           "pr_id": "ffd3f7cc6",
           "pr_po_flag": "N",
           "pr_item_id": "720541"
 }
```

from this data i want to search based on property value.
Example
If i give **"ORIGINAL"** ,based on this to get particular document from elasticsearch
Then how to solve this problem
Thank in advance

Comment: Are you using any NPM module for elastic search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is to match any field containing the value "ORIGINAL" you must use a ["multi match" query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html).

In your example, this mean :

```
POST /index/type/_search
{
   "query": {
      "multi_match": {
         "query": "ORIGINAL",
         "fields": [ "*" ],
         "lenient": true
      }
   }
}
```

But be aware that this way of querying  is not very efficient, it is better to match a single field with a "match" query :

```
POST /index/type/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
          "action1" : "ORIGINAL"
      }
   }
}
```

In node.js you can use [the official elastic library](https://www.npmjs.org/package/elasticsearch) to query elasticsearch more easily.

For example, in your case, you will write this kind of code with this library :

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'localhost:9200',
    log: 'trace'
});
client.search({
    index: 'index',
    type: 'type',
    body: {
        query: {
            match: {
                action1: 'ORIGINAL'
            }
        }
    }
}).then(function (resp) {
    var hits = resp.hits.hits;
    console.log(hits);
}, function (err) {
    console.trace(err.message);
});
```

Comment: I run this code in my system,but it getting error         { error: 'SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed; shardFailures {[pzDrmFNHRdaQ5EtxkpKGLA][purchage_order1][0]: SearchParseException[[purchage_order1][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"multi_match":{"query":"satishkumar","fields":["*"]}}}]]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: "satishkumar"]; }]',
  status: 400 }

Comment: If i want "action1" fields contains the documents then how to write the query

Comment: You're getting this error if you have some incompatible types fields (eg. integers) in your index. To prevent this, juste add ``lenient: true`` to your query. I'm gonna edit my answer with this parameter.
On the other hand, if you're only looking for a match on the "action1" field, the second query better fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for giving reponse